# Resource Count in Ant Scripts

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

I just need to know how to modify the code below so that ant determines the number of lines in my text files (Please note all text files here will have same number of lines but that number is not fixed) and automatically executes them based on the loop.

```html
<project name="ant-read-n-files" default="run" basedir=".">
  
  <!-- Load the ant contrib lib -->
  <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
    <classpath>
      <pathelement location="${basedir}/lib/ant-contrib.jar"/>
    </classpath>
  </taskdef>
  
  <target name="read">
    <!-- file a -->
    <loadfile property="textFileA" srcfile="${basedir}/files/aaa.txt">
      <filterchain>
        <headfilter lines="1" skip="${linenum}"/>
      </filterchain>
    </loadfile>
    <for param="line" list="${textFileA}" delimiter="${line.separator}">
      <sequential>
        <property name="textFileAValue" value="@{line}"/>
      </sequential>
    </for>
    <!-- file b -->
    <loadfile property="textFileB" srcfile="${basedir}/files/bbb.txt">
      <filterchain>
        <headfilter lines="1" skip="${linenum}"/>
      </filterchain>
    </loadfile>
    <for param="line" list="${textFileB}" delimiter="${line.separator}">
      <sequential>
        <property name="textFileBValue" value="@{line}"/>
      </sequential>
    </for>
    <!-- file c -->
    <loadfile property="textFileC" srcfile="${basedir}/files/ccc.txt">
      <filterchain>
        <headfilter lines="1" skip="${linenum}"/>
      </filterchain>
    </loadfile>
    <for param="line" list="${textFileC}" delimiter="${line.separator}">
      <sequential>
        <property name="textFileCValue" value="@{line}"/>
      </sequential>
    </for>
 
    <!-- Print them all -->
    <echo message="${textFileAValue}"/>
    <echo message="${textFileBValue}"/>
    <echo message="${textFileCValue}"/>
  </target>
 
  <target name="run">
    <foreach param="linenum" list="0,1,2" target="read"/>
  </target>
</project>
```

Here as you see list = "0,1,2" means the loop will verify first three lines of each text file, but i want this to be dynamic depending on the number of lines the files have.
Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Ashley

Comment: Have you considered integrating SonarQube into your build? Source code counts is one of the metrics that is gathered and reported to a web app dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

The below solution works here:-

```html
<project name="ant-read-n-files" default="run" basedir=".">
  
  <!-- Load the ant contrib lib -->
  <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
    <classpath>
      <pathelement location="${basedir}/lib/ant-contrib.jar"/>
    </classpath>
  </taskdef>
  
  <target name="read">
    <!-- file a -->
    <loadfile property="textFileA" srcfile="${basedir}/files/aaa.txt">
      <filterchain>
        <headfilter lines="1" skip="${linenum}"/>
      </filterchain>
    </loadfile>
    <for param="line" list="${textFileA}" delimiter="${line.separator}">
      <sequential>
        <property name="textFileAValue" value="@{line}"/>
      </sequential>
    </for>
    <!-- file b -->
    <loadfile property="textFileB" srcfile="${basedir}/files/bbb.txt">
      <filterchain>
        <headfilter lines="1" skip="${linenum}"/>
      </filterchain>
    </loadfile>
    <for param="line" list="${textFileB}" delimiter="${line.separator}">
      <sequential>
        <property name="textFileBValue" value="@{line}"/>
      </sequential>
    </for>
    <!-- file c -->
    <loadfile property="textFileC" srcfile="${basedir}/files/ccc.txt">
      <filterchain>
        <headfilter lines="1" skip="${linenum}"/>
      </filterchain>
    </loadfile>
    <for param="line" list="${textFileC}" delimiter="${line.separator}">
      <sequential>
        <property name="textFileCValue" value="@{line}"/>
      </sequential>
    </for>
 
    <!-- Print them all -->
    <echo message="${textFileAValue}"/>
    <echo message="${textFileBValue}"/>
    <echo message="${textFileCValue}"/>
  </target>
 
  <target name="run">
    <!-- Get number of lines of one of the files -->
    <loadfile property="textFile" srcfile="${basedir}/files/aaa.txt"/>
    <resourcecount property="line.count" count="0" when="eq">
      <tokens>
        <concat>
          <filterchain>
            <tokenfilter>
              <stringtokenizer delims="${line.separator}" />
            </tokenfilter>
          </filterchain>
          <propertyresource name="textFile" />
        </concat>
      </tokens>
    </resourcecount>
    <echo message="Number of lines: ${line.count}" />
 
    <script language="javascript">
      var list="", n=parseInt(project.getProperty("line.count"), 0);
      for (var i = 0; i &lt; n; i++) list += i + ",";  
      project.setProperty("list", list);
    </script>
    <foreach param="linenum" list="${list}" target="read"/>
 
  </target>
</project>
```